# Python27 numpy ndarray division behaviour

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

Odd issue I've come across:

```
img = np.array([[128,128],[0,255]])
img2 = img / 255.0
img /= 255.0
```

img2 returns [[0.502, 0.502], [0, 1]]
while img returns [[0, 0], [0, 1]]

surely these should be equivalent?

Comment: Thanks, that's it, didn't really know what to search for!